# Как можно задать позицию пользователя на YandexMapKit?

Tags: ios, swift, yandex-maps-api, yandexmapkit

Интересует вопрос как можно задать позицию пользователя с помощью Yandex Map Kit.

Сначала позиция задается геокоординатами, потом свайпами эта позиция пожет перемешаться по карте, также как позиция задается в Яндекс Go (Яндекс Такси).

Интересно что позиция пользователя должна быть смещена вертикально на величину `CGFloat` (панель с адресом с низу закрывает часть карты и это смещения является высотой панели)?

Зум должен быть зафиксирован по этой точке

Comment: Чтобы определить позицию пользователя первоначально достаточно использовать LocationManager. Затем сместите метку куда вам необходимо, если она будет draggable.